# reading value in CFDictionary with swift

Tags: macos, swift, core-graphics, key-value, core-foundation

I'm just starting with swift and cocoa. I'm trying to create a basic app that does image manipulation.

I've allready got all information of the image with this:

```
let imageRef:CGImageSourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, nil).takeUnretainedValue()
let imageDict:CFDictionaryRef = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageRef, 0, nil).takeUnretainedValue()
```

the dictionary contains following information:

```
{
    ColorModel = Gray;
    DPIHeight = 300;
    DPIWidth = 300;
    Depth = 1;
    Orientation = 1;
    PixelHeight = 4167;
    PixelWidth = 4167;
    "{Exif}" =     {
        ColorSpace = 65535;
        DateTimeDigitized = "2014:07:09 20:25:49";
        PixelXDimension = 4167;
        PixelYDimension = 4167;
    };
    "{TIFF}" =     {
        Compression = 1;
        DateTime = "2014:07:09 20:25:49";
        Orientation = 1;
        PhotometricInterpretation = 0;
        ResolutionUnit = 2;
        Software = "Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Macintosh)";
        XResolution = 300;
        YResolution = 300;
    };
}
```

now I'd like to read the value for the DPI with following code and there is some problem with "__conversion" I don't understand.

```
let dpiH:NSNumber = CFDictionaryGetValue(imageDict, kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth)
```

what am I doing wrong and how can I get to the desired values of the dictionary?

Comment: Can you post the whole error that you receive in xCode?

Comment: It stops compiling with that error: "Could not fing overload for '__conversion' that accepts the supplied arguments"

Comment: The error message above is not a copy: "fing".

Comment: Sry, typo. Should be "find". Typed it manually but if you like a copy from the navigator: `Could not find an overload for '__conversion' that accepts the supplied arguments`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found it much easier to access the properties by 'converting' the CFDictionary to a Swift dictionary.

```
let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageURL, nil)
let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary
let dpiWidth = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth] as NSNumber
```

---

Quick update for Swift 2.0 (excuse all the `if let`s - I just quickly crafted this code):

```
import UIKit
import ImageIO

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let imagePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "jpg") {
            let imageURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath)
            if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageURL, nil) {
                if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary? {
                    let pixelWidth = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as! Int
                    print("the image width is: \(pixelWidth)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been looking so long for an answer to extract EXIF information from images. This solved it. Thank you!

Comment: It does not work with Swift 2.0 as `CFDictionaryRef` can't be casted to `Dictionary`

Comment: @Darrarski   You can cast to Dictionary?  (note it needs to be cast as an optional).  I've updated with a quick example.  (ps.  it's much nicer to maker a comment re something is no longer working in a new version - rather than down voting).

Comment: @SoOverIt It looks like things have changed again--in XCode 7.3 I had to cast to an `NSDictionary`.