# How to retrieve image dimensions without loading CGImage into memory in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiimage

I want to get the image Size without loading into memory , i found in objective c but i need in swift can any one help me out

```
    #import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

   - (CGSize)sizeOfImageAtURL:(NSURL *)imageURL {
      CGSize imageSize = CGSizeZero;
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)imageURL, NULL);
    if (source) {
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:(NSString
   *)kCGImageSourceShouldCache];
 CFDictionaryRef properties = (NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, (CFDictionaryRef)options);
    if (properties) {
NSNumber *width = [(NSDictionary *)properties objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth];

   NSNumber *height = [(NSDictionary *)properties objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight];
   if ((width != nil) && (height != nil))
imageSize = CGSizeMake(width.floatValue, height.floatValue);
    CFRelease(properties);
     }
CFRelease(source);
    }
     return imageSize; }
```

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813583/reading-value-in-cfdictionary-with-swift/29091121#29091121 ?

Comment: Thanq Martin its worked for me